# jQuery on enter key submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I built a simple form that submits whenever you press ENTER. It works fine, but whenever I tried running a `.post` inside of it, the text in the textarea breaks when I press enter instead of submitting.

**What I mean by breaking**

---

The text in the textarea is 
| breaking

---

**This works fine**

```
// Submit comment on ENTER key pressed
    $("textarea[name=comment_body]").keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {

            alert(comment_body);
        }
    });
```

**This doesn't**

```
// Submit comment on ENTER key pressed
    $("textarea[name=comment_body]").keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {        
            var comment_body = $(this).val();    
            $.post("comments.php", {
                comment_body: comment_body
            }
            alert(comment_body);
        }
    });
```

How can I use jQuery .post inside of this without it failing?

Comment: You forgot the `event.preventDefault()`, also you probably meant `comment_body` instead of `remove_comment`

Comment: Thanks I didn't see that, and I had `event.preventDefault()` in there and it was messing up still.

Comment: You simply have a syntax error, you are missing the `)` parenthesis at the end of the `$.post` function call.

Comment: Well, that's the only improvement I did to your code to make it work as you can see in here http://jsfiddle.net/b2dbt/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it this way:

```
$("textarea[name=comment_body]").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {        
        var comment_body = $(this).val();    
        $.post("comments.php", {cb: comment_body}, function(data){
            alert(data.cb);
        }, "json");
});
```

What it seems to me you are posting the data `{comment_body:remove_comment}` to `comments.php`  via `$.post()` method of jQuery but you have not used the callback function in it.

Whatever you are posting to `comment.php` that is availble in the `data` param passed in the callback function.

Comment: The line in the textarea is still breaking when I press submit.

Comment: And i think you are sending the wrong data you should try with this `{cb: comment_body}`.

Answer (score 0):

> Syntax for post is: $.post(URL,data,callback);

```
$.post("comments.php",
   { 
     comment_body: remove_comment
   }, 
   function(result){
        alert(result.comment_body);
});
```